# Using Python need to print in csv format

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

```
{u'Test1': u'Result1', u'_id': ResultId('987600234565ade'), u'bugseverity': u'major'}
{u'Test2': u'Result2', u'_id': ResultId('987600234465ade'), u'bugseverity': u'minor'}
{u'Test3': u'Result3', u'_id': ResultId('9876002399999de'), u'bugseverity': u'minor'}
```

The output received after running query on a  mongodb is given above. Using this output I need to print values in csv format using python.

Comment: add some more detail about the input and output formats you are working with

Comment: what is ResultId()? How do you want the output to look? Please make a reproducible example in a python shell.

Comment: Similar output i received from mongodb. Requirement says to Make look like as in csv format as Headings:-  Test1     Resultid    bugseverity
                                                     Result1    9876002345     major
                                                                     65ade                               
In same way need to make list in csv

Comment: And what specific problem are you encountering when trying to do this? This is not a "give me the code" site.

Comment: @takendarkk I was new to coding including python and mongodb, My intention is to know how to start. As a newcomer i was expecting guidence  that all.

Comment: This is not the site for 'guidance' and 'tutorials'. It is a Q&A site for specific programming questions that arise while writing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I slightly changed the input data into a form which would make more sense technically speaking.

In addition I removed the `ResultId()` since this seems to be a special datatype which needs to be converted into a string separately before doing any further data handling after receiving the responses from the database.

However, I would suggest doing something like this using [`csv.Dictwriter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter):

```
import csv

# changed sample data key `Test` in order to have this key equal in all responses
# which would make more sense technically
data = [{u'Test': u'Result1', u'_id': '987600234565ade', u'bugseverity': u'major'},
{u'Test': u'Result2', u'_id': '987600234465ade', u'bugseverity': u'minor'},
{u'Test': u'Result3', u'_id': '9876002399999de', u'bugseverity': u'minor'}]

# define the column names
fieldnames = ['Test', '_id', 'bugseverity']

with open('dict.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for d in data:
        for key, value in d.items():
           writer.writerow(d)
```

Giving `dict.csv` as output:

```
Test,_id,bugseverity
Result1,987600234565ade,major
Result1,987600234565ade,major
Result1,987600234565ade,major
Result2,987600234465ade,minor
Result2,987600234465ade,minor
Result2,987600234465ade,minor
Result3,9876002399999de,minor
Result3,9876002399999de,minor
Result3,9876002399999de,minor
```